# function keeps asking for input

Tags: python-3.x, infinite-loop

The function I've written draws either a `square`, `triangle` or a `rectangle`. it asks the user to input which shape they want to be drawn. if the the input is not one of the following, it re-asks the user to enter a valid input:

**Valid inputs**

> ```
> square,
> triangle,
> rectangle,
> q #function Quits.
> ```

The problem I'm having, when the user types a valid input in the first time, the function carry's on perfectly and draws that shape. however, if the user first inputs an "invalid input", eg(circle), it asks the user to re-input a "valid input(shape)". when he does so, the function infinity keeps saying:

**error message**

> ```
> Unknown shape. Please try again
> Enter shape to draw (q to quit):
> ```

**code**

```
def get_valid_shape():
''' Asking the user to enter a valid shape that the function can draw '''
    shape = input("Enter shape to draw (q to quit): ").lower()
    unvalid_names1 = shape != "triangle" and shape != "square"
    unvalid_names2 = shape != "rectangle" and shape != "q"

    while unvalid_names1 == True and unvalid_names2 == True:
        print("Unknown shape. Please try again")
        shape = input("Enter shape to draw (q to quit): ").lower()
    if shape == "q":
        print("Goodbye")
    return
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're asking for the next value within the loop without a condition to break out of the loop. A simple fix would be:

```
def get_valid_shape():
    ''' Asking the user to enter a valid shape that the function can draw '''
    shape = input("Enter shape to draw (q to quit): ").lower()
    unvalid_names1 = shape != "triangle" and shape != "square"
    unvalid_names2 = shape != "rectangle" and shape != "q"
    quit = False

    while not quit and unvalid_names1 == True and unvalid_names2 == True:
        print("Unknown shape. Please try again")
        shape = input("Enter shape to draw (q to quit): ").lower()
        quit = shape == 'q'

    if shape == "q":
        print("Goodbye")
    return

get_valid_shape()
```

Apart from that, your code is very hard to understand. I've taken the liberty to produce another version. Readability is opinion really, but it also solves your problem while making (IMHO) more clear what you're trying to do:

```
def get_valid_shape():
    ''' Asking the user to enter a valid shape that the function can draw '''
    valid_shapes = set(['triangle', 'square', 'rectangle'])
    user_quit = False
    requested_shape = ''

    while True:
        requested_shape = input("Enter shape to draw (q to quit): ").lower()
        if requested_shape in valid_shapes:
            break
        elif requested_shape == 'q':
            user_quit = True
            break
        else:
            print('Invalid shape')

    if not user_quit:
        print('Would now print shape')
    else:
        print('Goodbye')

get_valid_shape()
```

Comment: Yes i do agree with you, Thanks!.
do you give me permission to use ur code for my task?

Comment: Sure. Code on StackOverflow [is under CC-BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12528)). I personally put a comment with a link to the SO answer if I copy code verbatim and post newer versions if I refactor it.